# What happens if you do not return callback

Tags: swift, swift2

Now I have the next function:

```
func processRequest(path: String, callback: ((json: JSON?, error: NSError?) -> Void)?) {
   // Code ...

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       callback?(json: JSON(data), error: nil)
   }
})
```

And how function is called:

```
processRequest("test") { (json: JSON?, error: NSError?) in
    // Play with returned data
}
```

And my question is: **What will happen if I don't return the callback?**
This is bad, or nothing terrible will happen?

Example of situation:

```
func processRequest(path: String, callback: ((json: JSON?, error: NSError?) -> Void)?) {
   // Code ...

   if (condition) {
       // What will happen if I am here and not return back "callback"
   } else {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
           callback?(json: JSON(data), error: nil)
       }
   }
})

processRequest("test") { (json: JSON?, error: NSError?) in
    // Play with returned data
}
```

Comment: Nothing terrible will happen and sometimes you actually need something like this. Most often though you want it to be called eventually, maybe after a 30 seconds timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a callback, you provide a block of code that `processRequest` decides when should be executed.

Given your implementation of `processRequest`, if you pass `nil` as callback param, simply no additional code is executed when `processRequest` decides that is time to invoke the callback function.

Infact the `callback` parameter is defined as `Optional`

```
callback: ((json: JSON?, error: NSError?) -> Void)?
```

and it's executed only if it is `not nil`

```
callback?(json: JSON(data), error: nil)
```

### Update

As you noted you are not passing a `nil` callback, you are passing a callback with an **empty body**. Given the current definition of `processRequest` the result is similar: nothing happens.

More specifically an empty closure is enqueued to the main queue (the one that has the right to update the user interface). I imagine this will produce an **infinitesimal overhead** in the system because that empty block of code will be synchronously added to the main queue, later on dequeued and finally executed.
Again, short answer: nothing happen.

Comment: Okey, but if I have set the callback and it is not nil, but I will not return it. In my logic, the code what was requested the function is waiting for callback returning, but I will not do it.

Comment: What do you mean with `I will not return it`?